# How to make a custom widget on JIRA that automates a SQL query on my server

Tags: sql, jira

I need to make a JIRA Gadget/ widget that takes SQL files on my computer and gives a report on JIRA and updates according to changes in the query at regular intervals.

1. Tried this  : https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/writing-a-jql-standalone-gadget/
   wanted an available widget already on JIRA instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking to write a plugin from scratch, or just looking for options.

Anyway, Adaptavist's plugin [Script Runner](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/) has this amazing functionality. See their example [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/recipes/misc/connecting-to-databases.html#_querying_the_current_jira_database).

You can schedule it to run whenever you want in Jira.